# Request Headers not available in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using a plugin which uploads image(s) trough Ajax. The js source of this plugin is [here](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/client/fileuploader.js).

If you see lines starting from 1200, you notice this:

```
// build query string
    params = params || {};
    params['qqfile'] = name;
    var queryString = qq.obj2url(params, this._options.action);

    xhr.open("POST", queryString, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(name));
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    xhr.send(file);
```

So basically, the filename uploaded is available as `qqfile` parameter OR as a Header var: `X-File-Name`. Both of these methods work perfectly in FF/Chrome with this ASP.NET MVC code:

```
public JsonResult AjaxUpload(String qqfile)
    {

        String fileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-file-name"];
        //rest of the code
    }
```

BUT in IE, none of these works...Header var is null (in Debug I clearly see that this parameter was not sent) and `1qqfile` is always `"System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper"`.

Does anybody know how can this be solved for IE?

Ps: Demo of this plugin is [here](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to do it like:

```
 public JsonResult AjaxUpload(HttpPostedFileWrapper qqfile)
    {
        //IE
        if (qqfile != null)
        {
            fileName = qqfile.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-file-name"];
        }
  //rest of the code
  }
```

Seems that in IE `HttpPostedFileWrapper` contains fileName and other properties (while in other browsers this is `null`), Pretty strange that I had to do a special case for IE.

Comment: well done sir :) thought this was going to be a headache. your solution works for me. only thing is qqFile.FileName gets back a full path for me so I had to split out the actual filename.